# WatchOS dynamic notifications not working on Xcode 11.1 and later - didReceive not called

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to get the Apple Watch SwiftUI notification tutorial working from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app. It works on Xcode 11.0, but fails on any more recent releases all the way from 11.1 through beta 11.3.

didReceive in the NotificationController is not being fired when a notification is received.  Here's the code for the NotificationController.swift file:

```
import WatchKit
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class NotificationController: WKUserNotificationHostingController<NotificationView> {
    var landmark: Landmark?
    var title: String?
    var message: String?

    let landmarkIndexKey = "landmarkIndex"

    override var body: NotificationView {
        NotificationView(title: title,
            message: message,
            landmark: landmark)
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    override func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        let userData = UserData()

        let notificationData =
            notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String: Any]

        let aps = notificationData?["aps"] as? [String: Any]
        let alert = aps?["alert"] as? [String: Any]

        title = alert?["title"] as? String
        message = alert?["body"] as? String

        if let index = notificationData?[landmarkIndexKey] as? Int {
            landmark = userData.landmarks[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here's the content of PushNotificationPayload.apns:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Silver Salmon Creek",
            "body": "You are within 5 miles of Silver Salmon Creek."
        },
        "category": "LandmarkNear",
        "thread-id": "5280"
    },

    "landmarkIndex": 1
}
```

Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem.  The watchOS 6.0 simulator works correctly with the didReceive function on the NotificationController.  When running the same code on the watchOS 6.1 simulator, didReceive is not called and any code used to render a dynamic notification is not executed.  For anyone else experiencing the same notification issues, I suggest running on the watchOS 6.0 simulator until this issue is resolved.

Comment: is it only an issue on the simulator? I'm seeing this on device too… watchOS 6.0 is fine, watchOS 6.1 is not.

Comment: It's an issue on both the device and simulator for 6.1.  It works fine on both device and simulator on 6.0.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. It's sad that Apple shipped watchOS 6.1 with SwiftUI notifications completely broken. Sadly the only solution seems to be to use WatchKit for notifications (or assuming it gets fixed in 6.2, set the deployment target to 6.2, but who would want to do that…)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same exact problem with Xcode 11.3. It failed in my code but not in Apple's completed project. Looking carefully at the tutorial code the payload there is (partially):

```
    "alert": {
        "body": "You are within 5 miles of Silver Salmon Creek."
        "title": "Silver Salmon Creek",
    },
```

and the payload in the completed project is:

```
    "alert": {
        "title": "Silver Salmon Creek",
        "body": "You are within 5 miles of Silver Salmon Creek."
    },
```

They reversed the two lines. However looking closely you see in their tutorial code the "body" line is missing the comma at the end. This causes the JSON parsing to fail (silently) and not generate the alert. Stick the comma in and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! Experienced the same issue with their tutorial in 2022. How does one detect/solve problems like this when using Xcode (apart from staring at the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Notifications are now working in WatchOS beta 6.1.1